# How can I find final velocity of an object which pass from earth's orbit?

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

I want to calculate direction and magnitude of an object such as a satellite which passes above the earth and goes far away. Suppose that all the parameters like the initial velocity and distance to the earth of the object, the object's and the earth's mass, etc, are known. Also suppose that, the earth is not moving in any direction.

How can I define mathematically the formula for the  velocity at the point where the earth is far away (almost doesn't apply any attractive force on the object)? Does the formula have any relationship with line integration?

[image: orbital-motion]

Comment: So to get the question clear. You want to find the final velocity after it has been diverted by the earth?

Comment: @SmarthBansal Yes exactly.

Comment: Use the conservation of angular momentum because in the planet's rest frame the speed of the spacecraft before and after will be the same (i.e., gravity is conservative).  In the frame of another body (e.g., the sun), the spacecraft's speed before and after will change.